# AWS Express Step Function - ECS Fargate task integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

AWS throws error that neither 'sync' nor 'wait for token' integration pattern is supported by express step function and the only supported service integration is 'request-response'. There is no example that I could find on how to execute a ECS Fargate container task from within express step function. Please provide if there is any reference available ?

Comment: It's not possible to use Fargate with Express Step Functions and wait for the task to complete (sync) or wait for a response (wait for token). The only option is to fire-and-forget (request-response) which triggers the Fargate task and immediately continues to the next state.